# ffmpeg: Audio input device not recognized

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording

What is needed for my ffmpeg command to recognize my audio input device?

The following reference has not helped resolve my problem: [enter link description here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop)

I want to record me talking (to my Windows laptop) while my screen activity is captured. While I have succeeded in capturing what's on the screen (by removing all mention of audio from my command), I have been unable to capture audio, as the device I mention is not recognized by ffmpeg. (I routinely use the default laptop for audio input to Audacity...surely there's some way to use it in this ffmpeg command, too.)

My audio devices:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

    [dshow @ 000000000044a940] DirectShow audio devices
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]  "Microphone Array (IDT High Defi"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone Array (IDT High Defi"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]  "Dock Mic (IDT High Definition A"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Dock Mic (IDT High Definition A"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]  "Jack Mic (IDT High Definition A"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Jack Mic (IDT High Definition A"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]  "Rec. Playback (IDT High Definit"
    [dshow @ 000000000044a940]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Rec. Playback (IDT High Definit"
```

The full name is found via regedit: Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)

Why isn't the audio input device found?

```
ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -i desktop -framerate 10 -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)" -vcodec libx264 "C:\jed\ffmpeg\_mydata\clip.mp4"

    [gdigrab @ 0000000000498540] Capturing whole desktop as 1366x768x32 at (0,0)
    [gdigrab @ 0000000000498540] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
    Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
      Duration: N/A, start: 1575576239.093815, bitrate: 1006131 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1366x768, 1006131 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
    [dshow @ 000000000049a5e0] Could not find audio only device with name [Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)] among source devices of type audio.
    [dshow @ 000000000049a5e0] Searching for audio device within video devices for Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
    [dshow @ 000000000049a5e0] Could not find audio only device with name [Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)] among source devices of type video.
    audio=Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): I/O error
```

Comment: Try with the exact string shown by ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Gyan was correct. Using the truncated expression, reported in the DirectShow list, worked.

```
audio="Microphone Array (IDT High Defi"
```